# Can't get data from form in django template into view?

Tags: django

Currently both of these print statements either log 'None' or just do not show at all. Even if I just print("hello') in the form.is_valid conditional I do not see it. Not sure what I have done wrong but the data was saving into the django admin but now it is not...

```
def create_user_account(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UserAccountForm(request.POST or None)
    print(request.POST.get('account_email'))

    if form.is_valid():
        print(form['account_email'].value())
        form.save()
        form = UserAccountForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/register_user.html', context)
```

and the html:

```
    {% block content %}
       <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
       </form>
    {% endblock  %}}
```

edit: i do get "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 when I send the request which is weird. I don't see a 201 or 302 like I would expect.

forms.py:

```
class UserAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'account_email',
            'country'
        ]

class UserAccount(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    account_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, null=False, 
    max_length=75)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

CONTINUED:

So I dropped the database, migrated and the table appeared like normal. I tried to save data and the same problem? BUT I also tried to add information manually through the admin site and got this error:
    OperationalError at /admin/profiles/useraccount/add/
    no such table: main.auth_user__old

So I updated to Django 3.0.6 and this solved the problem - can now add manually but still cannot add through the form.

Comment: If you add an else statement to print something when the form is not valid - does that appear?

Comment: i hoped this would work. it appears initially when the page renders but when I save the form I get `<WSGIRequest: POST '/'>
[19/May/2020 14:19:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 845`

Comment: Could you post your forms.py file? I had a form once, where not all required fields of the model where contained

Comment: @Sven  added forms.py - appreciate your help

Comment: well, now we would need your models.py too

Comment: @Sven should have seen that coming haha updated now

Comment: before the `if form.is_valid():` try to output the error in the terminal like this: `for field in form: for error in field.errors: print(error)` and see what is wrong with your form in the terminal

Comment: Your form is correct, so I don't have any solutions left. would try the hint of @YacineRouizi

Comment: @YacineRouizi I did this before the conditional but it never triggered print(error) - didnt see anything :/ thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Sven regardless thank you Sven :)

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. I don't know why it stopped working but it did. I feel I got finessed by indentation.

```
 def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserAccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserAccountForm()

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'registration/register_user.html', context)
```

Comment: with python, indentation is important. as you have written that your code works, I've fixed the indentation to make clear that wrong indentation is not the problem in your case

Comment: oh thank you. I really am not sure what the issue was but I went right through thr process again and things that I thought really were just preference made some sort of difference. I am sure I will figure it out but just glad it is back to working!